# Build libraries in linux and mac

Tags: linux, macos, qt, unix, static-libraries

I am building a Qt project under windows, linux, mac os

Since the project has lib dependencies, I have put the required libs for each platform, like:

```
win32:LIBS += lib1
unix:LIBS += lib2
mac:LIBS += lib3
```

The problem - if I build on mac, it looks for both unix and mac libs

If the unix lib is there I get a warning, saying it is the wrong format.

If the unix lib is missing, I get a build error.

How can I specify the mac lib different than linux ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it in the following way:

```
win32 {
    LIBS += lib1
} else:macx {
    LIBS += lib2
} else {
    LIBS += lib3
}
```